# Pronoun Reference

Tags: pronouns

> Ann liked to choose actors that resembled the characters that **he or she was** playing.

A. NO CHANGE

B. it was

C. they were

D. were

I understood that subject here (actors) is plural. A and B are out.

I chose D because C were felt a little awkward and "that" already conveys the idea.

However, the correct answer is C. Why C? not D?

Comment: "Actors" is plural.  "He or she" is singular.   Everything should match up properly, so "... that **they were** playing" sounds best.  However the entire sentence is awkward and should probably be rewritten.

Comment: "that were playing" (without they) would have meant the characters. "that they were playing" references the actors. Actors makes more sense (because "the characters were playing" begs the question—were playing WHAT? Angry Birds, or poker?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ann is female, so "he or she" can't refer to Ann.  "Characters" are played (not playing) so the pronoun must refer to "actors"

The word "actors" is plural. So using "they were" fits better. However the whole sentence is awkward and should probably be rewritten.

If you said "... resembled the characters that were playing", the subject of "were playing" would be "characters". But "characters were playing begs the question — what were they playing??". Instead, actors play characters. For this reason "D" is wrong.

Comment: It's a test question... rewriting isn't an option.

Comment: @Catija Thats obviously true, but I don't want to suggest that the sentence with "they were" is an example of excellent English.